# How to compile Speex source files to get a .dll file?

Tags: java, java-native-interface, speex

When I use NDK to compile Speex source files and a wrapper to get the .so file,it works fine.
But When I use MinGW64 to compile the files to get a .dll file for a project on Windows,the build failed.
Some error messages:

```
..\jni\libspeex\modes.h:39:25: fatal error: speex/speex.h: No such file or directory
```

and

```
..\jni\libspeex\arch.h:65:2: error: #error You now need to define either FIXED_POINT or FLOATING_POINT
```

Here is my wrapper:

```
#include <jni.h>

#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <speex/speex.h>

static int codec_open = 0;

static int dec_frame_size;
static int enc_frame_size;

static SpeexBits ebits, dbits;
void *enc_state;
void *dec_state;

static JavaVM *gJavaVM;

extern "C" JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_example_speexserver_codec_Speex_open(
        JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jint compression) {
    int tmp;

    if (codec_open++ != 0)
        return (jint) 0;

    speex_bits_init(&ebits);
    speex_bits_init(&dbits);

    enc_state = speex_encoder_init(&speex_nb_mode);
    dec_state = speex_decoder_init(&speex_nb_mode);
    tmp = compression;
    speex_encoder_ctl(enc_state, SPEEX_SET_QUALITY, &tmp);
    speex_encoder_ctl(enc_state, SPEEX_GET_FRAME_SIZE, &enc_frame_size);
    speex_decoder_ctl(dec_state, SPEEX_GET_FRAME_SIZE, &dec_frame_size);

    return (jint) 0;
}

extern "C" JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_example_speexserver_codec_Speex_encode(
        JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jshortArray lin, jint offset,
        jbyteArray encoded, jint size) {

    jshort buffer[enc_frame_size];
    jbyte output_buffer[enc_frame_size];
    int nsamples = (size - 1) / enc_frame_size + 1;
    int i, tot_bytes = 0;

    if (!codec_open)
        return 0;

    speex_bits_reset(&ebits);

    for (i = 0; i < nsamples; i++) {
        env->GetShortArrayRegion(lin, offset + i * enc_frame_size,
                enc_frame_size, buffer);
        speex_encode_int(enc_state, buffer, &ebits);
    }
    //env->GetShortArrayRegion(lin, offset, enc_frame_size, buffer);
    //speex_encode_int(enc_state, buffer, &ebits);

    tot_bytes = speex_bits_write(&ebits, (char *) output_buffer,
            enc_frame_size);
    env->SetByteArrayRegion(encoded, 0, tot_bytes, output_buffer);

    return (jint) tot_bytes;
}

extern "C" JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_example_speexserver_codec_Speex_decode(
        JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jbyteArray encoded, jshortArray lin,
        jint size) {

    jbyte buffer[dec_frame_size];
    jshort output_buffer[dec_frame_size];
    jsize encoded_length = size;

    if (!codec_open)
        return 0;
    //dec_frame_size >= size;
    env->GetByteArrayRegion(encoded, 0, encoded_length, buffer);
    speex_bits_read_from(&dbits, (char *) buffer, encoded_length);
    speex_decode_int(dec_state, &dbits, output_buffer);
    env->SetShortArrayRegion(lin, 0, dec_frame_size, output_buffer);

    return (jint) dec_frame_size;
}

extern "C" JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_example_speexserver_codec_Speex_getEncodeFrameSize(
        JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) {

    if (!codec_open)
        return 0;
    return (jint) enc_frame_size;

}

extern "C" JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_example_speexserver_codec_Speex_getDecodeFrameSize(
        JNIEnv * env, jobject obj) {
    if (!codec_open)
        return 0;
    return (jint) dec_frame_size;
}

extern "C" JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_example_speexserver_codec_Speex_close(
        JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) {

    if (--codec_open != 0)
        return;

    speex_bits_destroy(&ebits);
    speex_bits_destroy(&dbits);
    speex_decoder_destroy(dec_state);
    speex_encoder_destroy(enc_state);
}
```